# Bootstrap 4 Full width background on table header and rows but container on contents

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I want to use their [table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/) but I can't get it to fit the design I was given that looks roughly like the image below. Notice the full width background colors and how the table contents are within the Bootstrap `.container`:
[image: Rough example]

I need a full width dark background color on the `thead` and a full width light background color on the `tbody` but the elements should be inside the Bootstrap `.container`

I tried just putting the entire `table` in a `.container` but then I'm lost on how to make the full width background.

```css
.table .thead-dark th {
  background-color: #333333 !important;
}
tbody {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I tried adding the `.container` class to the `tr`'s but that didn't work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </div>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </div>
      </div>
    </tr>
    <tr class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </div>
      </div>
    </tr>
    <tr class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </div>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please add your code with HTML-structure and CSS you have used

Comment: Can you add your code as of how you are trying to achieve this.

Comment: Added my code as requested.

Comment: I think you can only have one element with the .container class in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table .thead-dark th {
  background-color: #333333 !important;
}
tbody {
  background: lightgrey;
}
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"></th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"></th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"></th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is just full width everything so it doesn't achieve what is required, which is a full width background all the way to the edges but container-ized contents that do not go all the way to the edges.

Comment: just remove the padding on container-fluid (I edited my snipet)

Comment: The contents, like the text, need to be inside the container. You have contents going all the way to the edges.

Answer (score 0):

use wrapp your `container` and `table` in to `tableFull` and check below `css` for`DIV` `tableFull`.

```css
.tableFull {
  background-color: #333333 !important;
  width:100%;
  height:51px;
}

.table .thead-dark th {
  background-color: #333333 !important;
}
tbody {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="tableFull">
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```